# How to get WebView open URL inside itself?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, webviewclient

i tried to make my webview opening URL's in the app but it doesn't work.
I am a newbie in Android Studio :)

Somehow it works but the links opens in Google Chrome outside the application.

Here's my MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView clanapp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        clanapp = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.clanapp);
        clanapp.getSettings().getJavaScriptEnabled();
        clanapp.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        String ENROLLMENT_URL;
        ENROLLMENT_URL = "https://www.google.ch";
        clanapp.loadUrl(ENROLLMENT_URL);


    }

    public final class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, request.getUrl());
            startActivity(i);
            return true;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` do? what happens if you remove that override or replace everything inside the function with `return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);` ? returning true there means you are aborting the url load on your webview.

Comment: wow thanks that was kinda simple solution.

Now overwrited the line :

'public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)' 

with

'public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)'

deleted: 

'Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, request.getUrl());
            startActivity(i);'

and set 

'return false'

Thank you very much